# Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug on windows 8.1

Tags: react-native

I am creating the react-native app on windows 8.1 platform, while I am creating build using react-native run-android its giving me the following error. Please help me on the same.

```
Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:611:11)
at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:629:13)
at runOnAllDevices (E:\showTimes\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:299:19)
at buildAndRun (E:\showTimes\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:135:12)
at isPackagerRunning.then.result (E:\showTimes\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:65:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: Can you add more error log?

Comment: have you solved?

Comment: No..I didn't get any answer..:(

Answer (score 2):

create local.properties file in project root/android then add path to your SDK location 
my case

```
sdk.dir = C:\\Users\\<userName>\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
```